# C++ Code Possible Issues

Tags: c++

Are there any errors in the code below?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>


int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> myVector;

  myVector.push_back("one");
  myVector.push_back("two");
  myVector.push_back("three");
  myVector.push_back("four");
  myVector.push_back("five");

  std::sort(myVector.begin(),myVector.end(),std::less_equal<std::string>());
  std::string& str = myVector.back();

  std::cout << str << std::endl;

  std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = myVector.begin();

  myVector.push_back("six");
  myVector.push_back("seven");

  std::cout << *it << std::endl;

  return 0; 
}
```

I could only see that by assigning the address of the last element of the vector to str it means that if you remove that element then str is empty, and that this can cause un expected behaviour and even run time issues.

Comment: Iterators and internal references into a `std::vector` are invlaidated after a `push_back`.

Comment: `std::less_equal` does not provide the necessary strict weak ordering. It is not reflexive (x ≤ x is not false).

Comment: It is definitely reflexive. Which is the problem.

Comment: @chris Actually, it *is* reflexive. And `sort` requires non-reflexive.

Comment: @sjdowling That's not universally true. It only applies if the vector needs to resize its underlying storage to be able to perform the push_back. If its size is already sufficient, neither references nor iterators will be invalidated by push_back.

Comment: @Angew, Whoops, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there, the problem is this line:

```
std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

That comes after several `push_back`s. Since `vector` is resizeable, it is possible that between you saving off your iterator and adding more elements, that the container had to allocate more memory. If it did have to, then your iterator would be pointing to an element that is no longer part of the `vector`. It may not clearly look like it, but you have [potentially] a dangling pointer.

Also, same with:

```
std::string& str = myVector.back();
```

That reference could become invalidated after the `push_back`s.